# Text (date) stamp on photo

Tags: android, date, camera, photo

Is it possible merge text and photo taken from camera?
I would like to stamp date and time on photo but I don't find anything on Google.

Comment: how to set time stamp to bottom  ??

Answer (score 8):

Use below code to achieve what you required.

```
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cuty); // the original file is cuty.jpg i added in resources
        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system

        Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
        Paint tPaint = new Paint();
        tPaint.setTextSize(35);
        tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
        float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
        cs.drawText(dateTime, 20f, height+15f, tPaint);
        try {
            dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/timeStampedImage.jpg")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You have to use below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have any doubts feel free to ask. I am adding time stamp at top left corner of image, you can change it to anywhere on the image.

For my device the path is **/sdcard** to access external SD card, it may vary for other devices. Some devices may have **/mnt/sdcard** may be it is for internal sd cards. Just check it while before using this code snippet.

Comment: hello Yugandhar Babu..hope you are doing well...i want to add date and time stamp on video recording , when i play video display date and time as like your above image code do..i am done with your image code and its work well now i want to add this funtionality for video also..any help would be appreciated..thanks..

Comment: @saurabhtrivedi sorry, i can't help for your requirement. Now  i am busy with android porting than android app development.

Comment: @YugandharBabu ,Did you got any solution for Video ?

Comment: I am getting out of memory exception when i load large image taken from camera, i also tried android:largeHeap="true" still nothing

Answer (score 2):

- Create a bitmap object from the byte[] array that you get from JPEG picture callback using the method `decodeByteArray`
- Create a canvas object using the bitmap you created above
- Use the method `drawText` on the canvas object to write the text on the photo.