# how can I add timestamp in captured photo in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, watermark

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap src= (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawText(dateTime , 0, 0, null);
        click_image_id.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

It get crashed , if I change and commented canvas implementation like
//

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

Bitmap src= (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

click_image_id.setImageBitmap(src);
```

it execute view, but i need timestamp in the image , need help experts

Comment: Can you post the crash log please?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Paint.mBidiFlags' on a null object reference @BogdanAndroid

Comment: Process: workman.com.internetlistener, PID: 22783
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {workman.com.internetlistener/workman.com.Watermarker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Paint.mBidiFlags' on a null object reference  @BogdanAndroid

Comment: Ok, I got your problem @SECECSEA , I will write the answer now

Comment: take a picture and view in same activity , so that I have wrote onActivityResult to get the picture, without canvas object implementation, i can veiw the image on same activity like // 2 code , but while add canvas to add watermark in the captured image by the bitmap it crashed ., can u get my point @BogdanAndroid

Comment: after add paint object not get crashed, but now the date and time is not in picture , can u help for this alone @BogdanAndroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and configure a `Paint` object and use it in the `canvas.drawText()`. Try something like this (taken from [this](https://medium.com/@travells2323/android-draw-text-to-bitmap-8251f6d79150) article).

```
private fun drawTextToBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, textSize: Int = 78, text: String): Bitmap {

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    
    // new antialised Paint - empty constructor does also work
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.color = Color.BLACK
    
    // text size in pixels
    val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
    paint.textSize = (textSize * scale).roundToInt().toFloat()

    //custom fonts or a default font
    val fontFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.acrobat)
    paint.typeface = Typeface.create(fontFace, Typeface.NORMAL)


    // draw text to the Canvas center
    val bounds = Rect()
    //draw the text
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)

    //x and y defines the position of the text, starting in the top left corner
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint)
    return bitmap
}
```

Comment: The empty constructor of Paint object use default data, it's not totally necessary to configure it but your answer could help someone who are looking for customization of the Paint object.

Comment: The constructor may be empty, yes. But you cannot use it for the purpose of this question without further configuration.

Comment: Yes you can, check my last answer edit, i have tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need the `Paint` object that that `drawText()` needs, it CAN NOT be null. Here the code that will solve your NPE.

Edit:

The second problem was the location of the drawed text, copy and paste this solution. It will place a black text in the bottom left corner with the date.

If you want to customize the text, customize the `Paint` object. I checked this code and it works correctly.

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap src= (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawText(dateTime , 0, h, new Paint());
        click_image_id.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah now it not crashed , but the date and time is not in the picture @Bogdan Android

Comment: @SECECSEA You must configure your `Paint` object before using it. [Here](https://medium.com/@travells2323/android-draw-text-to-bitmap-8251f6d79150) is an article with a detailed example.

Comment: Ok, found again the problem, just give me a second @SECECSEA

Comment: Ok, done, copy the new code and check it @SECECSEA.

Answer (score 0):

Atlast this code is working thanks for your effort @ASP and @BogdonAndroid

i have check the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045826/text-date-stamp-on-photo)

```
public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, boolean underline) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(15);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
    canvas.drawBitmap(src,0,0,null);
    canvas.drawText(dateTime, 20f, height+15f, tPaint);
    return result;}
```